# How do I compile the SFML libraries with VSCode at Windows

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-code, sfml

I have this trouble, I can't compile my SFML program at Windows 10, I have Linux, and at Linux I don't have problems, but here in windows, I don't know how to link the SFML libraries with VSCode. Help me please.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Post the commands/code you have tried and post the results/errors as text in your question.

Comment: If you install MinGW, everything works just like you know it from Linux command wise. As an alternative, just install Visual Studio, which will basically do it for you. Overall, since SFML is built using CMake, on either platform you can just run `cmake source/dir && cmake --build . --config release` (or similar for other configurations) to build.

Answer (score 0):

First of all VSCode is only an editor like atom, Sublime etc. 
So you need a compiler.
The simplest way to compile SFML under Windows is to use Visual Studio. 
If you want to have an experience similar to Linux you should use MinGW.
MinGW is a Windows port of GNU.